I have made a startup script but it only can run as an user, not root, how can I make it work?
there are 4 scripts that should be started after reboot as user "appian":

/opt/appian/appian_home/services/bin/start.sh -p Password -s all
/opt/appian/appian_home/data-server/bin/start.sh
/opt/appian/appian_home/search-server/bin/start.sh
/opt/appian/appian_home/tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/start-appserver.sh

Here is some code
#!/bin/bash

# Log file for debugging
    LOG_FILE="/var/log/appian_services_start.log"

# Start services and log the process
    echo "Starting Appian services: $(date)" >> $LOG_FILE

# Script 1: Start services with credentials
    /opt/appian/appian_home/services/bin/start.sh -p Password -s all >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
    echo "Service 1 started: services/bin/start.sh" >> $LOG_FILE

# Wait for 30 seconds
    sleep 30

# Script 2: Start data-server
    /opt/appian/appian_home/data-server/bin/start.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
    echo "Service 2 started: data-server/bin/start.sh" >> $LOG_FILE

# Wait for 10 seconds
    sleep 10

# Script 3: Start search-server
    /opt/appian/appian_home/search-server/bin/start.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
    echo "Service 3 started: search-server/bin/start.sh" >> $LOG_FILE

# Wait for 10 seconds
    sleep 10

# Script 4: Start Tomcat server
    /opt/appian/appian_home/tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/start-appserver.sh >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
    echo "Service 4 started: tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/start-appserver.sh" >> $LOG_FILE

    echo "All services started successfully: $(date)" >> $LOG_FILE
                                                                                 
# These are the manual steps what works 
    dzdo su - appian /opt/appian/appian_home/services/bin/start.sh -p Password -s all
    dzdo su - appian /opt/appian/appian_home/data-server/bin/start.sh
    dzdo su - appian /opt/appian/appian_home/search-server/bin/start.sh
    dzdo su - appian /opt/appian/appian_home/tomcat/apache-tomcat/bin/start-appserver.sh`

How to arrange the startup script that after a reboot the scripts can be excecuted by the appian user?

To hide the password (from bash_history) in manual steps, there are several ways. I often do : some_command ... -p "$( cat )" ... :  you will then see it wait for you to enter something to cat's STDIN : type the password there and finish it by ctrl+d ctrl+d (twice, to terminate the input at the end of that line) or just by Enter ctrl-d (same effect)
You should definitely try to find a way to hide the password in your script as well ( -p "${some_variable}" is a tiny bit better, if that var content is defined in a protected file only accessible by the right processes, but not perfect)

You should do an service to run the main script who starts the others:
[Unit]
 Description=Startup of my scripts
 After=syslog.target network.target
 StartLimitIntervalSec=0
 
[Service]
Type=simple
#Restart=on-failure
#RestartSec=180
User=appian
ExecStart=/path/to/mymainscript.sh
PIDFile=/run/myscripstsappian.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
~                                   
#

Of course there more than this way and there is improvements to be made.
But it´s a start.

Hi Thank you for your answer, I have a service, but it doesn't work. the user appian is not a root user, all the rights are good. Can you explain the pidfile in the script? [Unit]
Description=Start Appian Services after reboot
After=network.target [Service]
Type=oneshot
User=appian
ExecStart=/path/to/start_appian_services.sh
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal [Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
